# Web Service not defined. VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services

Hi was wondering if anyone had come accross this problem before in where a web service was defined yesterday come to try today and its no longer defined.

Ive updated the web-reference folder no errors. The strange thing is when I type in the reference as in

```
DIM ws AS NEW service.serviseasmx()
```

What normally happens if VS would pick up on the service in the drop down could I have messed up my web.config file if so is it fixable or any other suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: have you done a "Rebuild" or "Clean Solution"?  Have you saved and shut down and restarted the project?

Comment: Have you tried removing and readding the reference?

Comment: I've found VS to need to close and restart if auto complete isn't working properly.